# Can I create a balloon callout on an address point on a published map?

Tags: arcpy

Very new to this, so please excuse any ignorant question!  I've created a vb.net app to open a published map in ArcReader.  Have a few questions...

First,  I started with the query attribute sample to find an address, zoom to the point on the map, and flash.   I'd like to have a balloon callout display showing the address on the map as well.

From this site, I tried the following code (below), but trying to use ICallout and IFormattedText Symbol tells me 'ambiguously defined for esri.ArcGIS.Display'.

I'm using ArcReaderControl to build this and then adding on to it.  Have I missed something simple?

Below is the code:

```
Private Sub AddBalloonCallout(ByVal activeView As IActiveView, ByVal text As String, ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double)

        Dim pTextElement As ITextElement
        Dim pElement As IElement
        Dim pPoint As IPoint
        Dim pCallout As ICallout
        Dim pTextSymbol As IFormattedTextSymbol
        Dim pGraphicsContainer As IGraphicsContainer
        Dim midX As Double, midY As Double


        Dim pCallout As ICallout
        pTextSymbol = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.TextSymbol



        'Dim pTextSymbol As IFormattedTextSymbol
        Dim pGraphicsContainer As IGraphicsContainer
        Dim midX As Double, midY As Double

        'Create a new text element 
        pTextElement = New TextElement
        pElement = CType(pTextElement, IElement) 'QI 
        pTextElement.Text = "Text callout" & vbCrLf & text

        'Position the new element on the active view's center point 
        midX = (activeView.Extent.XMax + activeView.Extent.XMin) / 2
        midY = (activeView.Extent.YMax + activeView.Extent.YMin) / 2
        pPoint = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point
        pPoint.PutCoords(midX, midY)
        pElement.Geometry = pPoint

        'Set the text element symbology to a default balloon callout 
        pTextSymbol = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.TextSymbol
        pCallout = New BalloonCallout
        pTextSymbol.Background = CType(pCallout, ITextBackground)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
////////////////////////////////balloon callout formatting init//////////////////////////
IBalloonCallout balloonCallout = new BalloonCalloutClass();
pTextElement = new TextElementClass();
pFormattedTextSymbol = new TextSymbol() as IFormattedTextSymbol;
TextSymbolClass textSymbolclass = new TextSymbolClass();
textSymbolclass.Background = balloonCallout as ITextBackground; //the bare minimum
balloonCallout.Style = esriBalloonCalloutStyle.esriBCSRoundedRectangle;
balloonCalloutTextSymbol = textSymbolclass as ITextSymbol;
balloonCalloutTextSymbol.Font = ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.Local.Converter.ToStdFont(new Font("Arial", 10.0f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular));
////////////////////////////////balloon callout formatting init//////////////////////////

ISymbol thissymbol = balloonCalloutTextSymbol as ISymbol;//textsymbol was init'd to a balloon callout above
object thisobj = thissymbol as object;
mapControl.DrawText(displayPoint, someTextString, ref thisobj);
```

//I'm using ArcReaderControl to build this and then adding on to it. Have I missed something simple?

I don't find it simple or intuitive at all